Estimation of the eigenvalue of a matrix
Let $A_n$ be a $n×n$ matrix with entries $a_{ij}=n-|i-j|$, let $\lambda_n$ be the largest eigenvalue of $A_n$, find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\lambda_n }{n^2}$
I find it hard to compute the eigenvalue of $A_n$ directly, if there any way to estimate the eigenvalues of $A_n$ ?

What did you find hard when you were computing the eigenvalues ?

This seems to be an interesting question. What have you tried so far? Numerical efforts suggest a value of around $0.675$.

The inverse of this matrix might be easier to work with
